How do Change behaviour of the side buttons on my mouse?
I have two mice. One is a Logitech MX Anywhere 3. The other is a Lenovo Pro Bluetooth Mouse.
They both the normal two buttons, a single clickable vertical scroll wheel and two extra buttons on the side.
On both the mice, clicking the side buttons goes back and forward on a web browser but on the Logitech, holding one of the side buttons and scrolling scrolls the window horizontally.
Is there a way to get this horizontal scrolling to work on the Lenovo?
For info, I'm running Gnome 46 on Wayland on NixOS (although had identical behaviour on an Ubuntu 24.04).
I should mention, because I've found loads of questions about this, I am not talking about a horizontal tilt wheel; I'm talking about scrolling vertically whilst holding a side button.

sudo apt install piper
If that doesn't work, reboot into Windows and use Logitech's Windows software(Logitech G HUB) to reconfigure your mouse. If your mouse buttons can be reprogrammed, changes will persist.

I don't have access to Windows and it's the Lenovo mouse I want to change. Piper, however, looks interesting although it doesn't seem to support my mouse. I shall look into that further.
